# Minimum operations to find tangent to circle

Tags: geometry, circles, geometric-construction, tangent-line

I've been playing the game Euclidea 3, and I can't really wrap my mind around one of the minimal solutions:

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zublg6ZevKo&feature=youtu.be&t=9

The object is to get a tangent line on right of the blue circle with only 3 operations. The minimum solution involves only 2 compass operations (shown above as the gray circles) and the final operation is a straight edge through the point on the blue circle and the intersection of the two compass operations.

My question is: how does this work? How do these two compass operations always result in a point tangential to the blue circle's point?

Comment: I thinks we are constructing 2 circles just to get interesting points for blue circle and to join to get tangent to blue circle

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[image: The construction]

In the construction above, we are given the circle centred on $O$ (black) and the point $P$. We pick an arbitrary point $A$ on the circle and construct two more circles (in light grey) which intersect in $B$ and $C$; a segment of the tangent is then $PC$. $Z$ is a point on the black circle, on the other side of the chord $PB$ from $A$, and is solely a component of our proof: that $\angle OPC=90^\circ$. Line segments of the same length have the same colour (except the ones incident to $Z$).

Say $\angle BPA=x$. Since $\triangle PAB$ and $\triangle CAP$ are congruent and isosceles, $\angle APC=x$.

$\angle PAB$ is $180^\circ-2x$, and since quadrilateral $PABZ$ is cyclic, $\angle PAB+\angle BZP=180^\circ$, or $\angle BZP=2x$. By the inscribed angle theorem, $\angle BOP=4x$.

Since $\triangle BOP$ is isosceles, $\angle OPB=\frac12(180^\circ-4x)=90^\circ-2x$. Then
$$\angle OPC=\angle OPB+\angle BPA+\angle APC=90^\circ-2x+x+x=90^\circ$$
Hence $PC$ is tangent to the black circle at $P$.

Comment: Nice explanation!

Answer (score 7):

My version is not a strict formal proof, but rather an intuition behind the idea. I hope it helps to get the point without having to dive into a lot of formal steps and theorems.

There are actually two major symmetries in this construct that make the whole thing possible.

The first is the reflection symmetry of the circle *p* relative to the *AB* line. It guarantees that the two arcs, *DB* and *BE*, are equal, which in turn implies that *DE* arc is twice as long as *DB* arc.

Now pretend this construct in motion. When we move point *B* along the circle *p*, keeping all given constraints, the *DE* segment rotates relative to the *AD* line twice as fast as *DB* does and, consequently, $\angle ADE$ changes twice as fast as $\angle ADB$.

Here we have to note the second major symmetry -- the symmetry of the circles *q* and *s* relative to the *DB* line. This symmetry implies that $\angle EDB = \angle GDB$.

Continuing to look at this in motion, we notice that when we move *B*, say, towards *D*, the *DE* segment 'chases' the *DB* line with twice its speed. At the same time, the *DG* segment symmetrically 'meets' the *DB* line with the same speed as *DE*, but in the **opposite** direction. This neatly guides us to the notion that the *DG* segment stays fixed, or, in other words, $\angle ADG = const$.

Now all we're left to do is to find the actual value of $\angle ADG$. We can continue to look at the motion described above, pretending that *B* approaches *D*. We see that all the lines *DE*, *DB*, and *DG* approach each other and become one line as *B* becomes *D*. And this line is clearly tangent to the circle *p*. But *DG* was not even moving relative to *AD*, so it should have been the same tangent line from the very beginning.

Hope that helps.

[image: two symmetries relative to blue lines]

Comment: "... which in turn implies that DE is twice as long as DB." This confused me, I thought you were talking about the lines. But playing with it for a bit I sees it's about that arcs, that makes sense!

Comment: @RvdV sorry for this, I've clarified that part, based on your comment

Comment: Thanks, it's a nice explanation and it helped me!

Answer (score 3):

(1) $\angle MXN = 90^0$. (Angles in semi-circle)

(2) $\angle RTN = 90^0$. (Line of centers is perpendicular to common chord)

(1) and (2) imply XM // TR.

[image]

From (2), we have $\triangle RTN \cong \triangle RTX$. Then, $\angle 1 = \angle 2$.

Also, $\angle 2 = \angle 3$ , $\angle 2 = \angle 4$ and $\angle 4 = \angle 5$.

Therefore, $\angle 5 = \angle 1$. This means MRN is tangent to the blue circle by “converse of angles in alternate segment”.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The original circle had center $A$ and $B$ on the boundary, and all of the red line segments are radii.  Point $C$ on that circle was arbitrarily chosen, and the circle with center $C$ and $B$ on its boundary (with green radii) meets the original circle at $D$.  Finally, the circle whose center is $B$ and has $D$ on its boundary is drawn (with blue radii), and $E$ is where that circle meets the second circle.

Claim: $\angle ABE$ is a right angle.

Proof:

- $C$ is equidistant from $B$ and $D$, and so is $A$.  Therefore, the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{BD}$ (i.e. the locus of all points equidistant from $B$ and $D$) is $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ and thus $\triangle BCF$ is a right triangle.
- $\angle DBC\cong\angle CBE$ as they are corresponding angles in the two congruent blue-green-green triangles.
- $\angle ABC\cong \angle BCA$, as they are the base angles in an isosceles triangle.
- Therefore, $m\angle ABE=m\angle ABC+\angle CBE = m\angle BCF + m\angle FBC=90^\circ$