# Construct tangent through point on circle in 3 steps

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

I'm stuck in the Euclidea app in level 2.8, which asks:

> Given a circle and a point on that circle, construct the tangent through that point using only 3 elemental steps.

Their [FAQ](https://www.euclidea.xyz/en/faq#level_2_8_with_3E) already mentions that the steps are circle, circle, line (and these are the only allowed construction steps). The strange thing is that neither [the German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kreistangente#Konstruktion_der_Tangente) nor [the English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_lines_to_circles#Compass_and_straightedge_constructions) describe how to do this construction in only 3 steps, although I think the shortest way should be documented there.

Comment: Is it possible that the exercise begins with a line or ray already drawn from the center of the circle through the point "on the circle"?  If so, I can see how circle, circle, line would complete the exercise (the line being the tangent).  Not being able to see what is given in this exercise handicaps your Readers.

Comment: No, only the circle and the point are given.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematics StackExchange [has already answered this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961629/minimum-operations-to-find-tangent-to-circle), even including a proof based on the inscribed angle theorem, among a few theorems.

Answer (score 0):

I would say :

**1)** Draw a ligne that pass through $P$ and the center of the circle $O$

**2)** With a compass draw a point that $Q$ s.t. $P$ is the middle of $OQ$.

**3)** Draw the bisection of $[P,Q]$, and you have it !

Comment: This is the construction already given in Wikipedia. But the Euclidian app claims there is a shorter way, which involves only circles and lines, but not composite steps like bisections.